# any Identifiable can't conform to 'Identifiable'

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5.7

**update: add same error about Hashable**

---

I have created an `Identifiable` compliant protocol and compliant structures. Then, when I create the list and reference it in `ForEach`, I get the error `Type 'any TestProtocol' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'`(I get the same error about `Hashable`).

How should I fix this program?

If I write `ForEach(list, id: \.id)` , it works, but I don't think it makes sense to be Identifiable compliant.

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol TestProtocol: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID { get set }
    var name: String { get set }
    
    func greeting() -> String
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

extension TestProtocol {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

struct Person: TestProtocol {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    
    func greeting() -> String {
        return "my name is \(name) and I'm a human."
    }
}

struct Dog: TestProtocol {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    
    func greeting() -> String {
        return "my name is \(name) and I'm a dog."
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var list: [any TestProtocol] = [Person(name: "p1"), Dog(name: "d1")]
    @State var selected: any TestProtocol
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selected) { // Type 'any TestProtocol' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
                ForEach(list) { l in // Type 'any TestProtocol' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'
                    Text(l.greeting()).tag(l) // Type 'any TestProtocol' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
                }
            } label: {
                Text("select")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean with _"... but I don't think it makes sense to be Identifiable compliant."_. So you don't want your protocol to extend `Identifiable` at all or is it using the `id` property that doesn't make sense?

Comment: To design it this way, you actually need to implement `RandomAccessCollection` instead of `var list: [any TestProtocol]`, which can contain your types like `Person`, `Dog`. Or, you can go a simpler route: create `class ListItem: Identifiable, Hashable {` with `open func greeting() -> String { fatalError("Must be implemented") }` and then make descendants `Person` and `Dog` implement this function (or any other such functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message complaining about `Hashable` is a "red hering". The protocol `TestProtocol`, and therefor all structs conforming to it, conforms to `Hashable`.

```
let person = Person(name: "IAmHashable")
print(person.hashValue)
```

The reason this is failing is within the `Picker`. It needs a concrete type and not a protocol. One solution would be to create a "Container" type and a custom binding that handles this.

```
struct Container: Identifiable, Hashable{
    //implement the same equality as in your TestProtocol
    static func == (lhs: Container, rhs: Container) -> Bool {
        rhs.wrapped.id == lhs.wrapped.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(wrapped)
    }
    
    var wrapped: any TestProtocol
    //for convenience
    var id: UUID {wrapped.id}
}
```

and the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let startArr: [any TestProtocol] = [Person(name: "p1"), Dog(name: "d1")]
    @State private var selected: (any TestProtocol)?

    var body: some View {
        // list of wrapped protocols
        var list: [Container] = { startArr.map{Container(wrapped: $0)}}()
        // binding
        let selectionBinding: Binding<Container> = .init {
            let returninstance = list.first { cont in
                cont.id == selected?.id
            }
            return returninstance ?? list[0]
        } set: { container in
            selected = container.wrapped
        }
        
        // viewCode
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: selectionBinding) {
                ForEach(list) { l in
                    Text(l.wrapped.greeting())
                        .tag(l)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("select")
            }
            // confirmation selection changed
            Text(selected?.name ?? "no Selection")
        }
    }
}
```

### Remarks:

This solution has a few **drawbacks**:

- your initial array `startArr` should never be empty, else `return returninstance ?? list[0]` will break you code. This can be handled, but I think this is out of the scope of this question.
- the equality comparison of `Container` needs to be the same as in `TestProtocol` as you cannot compare two `any Protocol`s
- on the appearance of `ContainerView` `selected` will be nil until something is selected. Any usage, e.g.: the `Text` element in this case, needs to deal with this. But you could probably set this in `.onApear`.